# Eight queens puzzle

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to solve a 8-queens problem with hill climbing algorithm. I have a problem with the "generate_node"method (this method given a node, generate all its neighbors)of the following class. In particular the problem consists into the updating of the matrix of the Node "parent" but I didn't forecast this update in my implementation. This updating  cause a wrong generation of the child nodes.

```
package algoritmi_ricerca_locale;
import java.util.*;

public class Hill_Climbing {

    private final Node root;

    public Hill_Climbing(Node root){
        this.root=root;
    }

    public Node getRoot(){
        return root;
    } 

    public List<Node> generate_child(Node parent){

        List<Node> node_list=new LinkedList<>();    
        char [][] child_state;

        for (int j=0;j<8;j++){
            for (int i=0;i<8;i++){
                if (parent.getState()[i][j]==' '){

                    int count_conf=0;
                    child_state=parent.getState(); 

                    for(int t=0;t<8;t++){
                        if(child_state[t][j]=='*'){

                            child_state[t][j]=' ';
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    child_state[i][j]='*';

                    for (int m=0;m<8;m++){
                        for (int n=0;n<8;n++){
                            if(child_state[n][m]=='*'){
                                for(int k=m+1;k<8;k++){
                                    if(child_state[n][k]=='*'){
                                        count_conf++;

                                    }
                                }  

                                for (int h=n+1,k=m+1;h<8 && k<8;h++,k++){
                                    if(child_state[h][k]=='*'){
                                        count_conf++;    

                                    }
                                }

                                for (int h=n-1,k=m+1;h>0 && k<8;h--,k++){
                                    if(child_state[h][k]=='*'){
                                        count_conf++;    
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    node_list.add(new Node(count_conf,child_state));
                }    
                else{

                    continue;

                }

            }
        }

        System.out.println(node_list.size());
        return node_list;
    }



    public Node choose_Node (List<Node> a,int fobj){
        int min=fobj;
        int index=-1;
        System.out.println(a.size());
        for(int i=0;i< a.size();i++){
            if(a.get(i).getFunc_Obj()<min){
                min=a.get(i).getFunc_Obj();
                index=i;
            }
        }
        if(index==-1){

            return null;    
        }
        else{
            return a.get(index);
        }
    }


    public Node algorithm(){
        Node selected_node=new Node() ;
        if ( root.getFunc_Obj()==0){

            System.out.println("Root=Goal"); 
            getRoot();
        }

        else {
            List <Node> neighbours;
            selected_node =root;
            neighbours= generate_child(selected_node);
            while (choose_Node(neighbours,selected_node.getFunc_Obj())!=null){
                selected_node=choose_Node(neighbours,selected_node.getFunc_Obj());
                if (selected_node.getFunc_Obj()==0){

                    System.out.println("Goal state trovato");   
                    return selected_node;

                }  
                neighbours.clear();
                neighbours= generate_child(selected_node);

            }


        }
        System.out.println("Goal state non trovato");
        return selected_node;

    }
}
```

the class Node is the following:

```
public class Node {

    private int func_obj;
    private  char state [][];

    public Node(){

    }

    public Node(int func_obj, char [][] state){ 
        this.func_obj=func_obj;
        this.state=state;
    }

    public int getFunc_Obj(){
        return func_obj;
    }

    public char [][] getState(){
        return state;
    }
}
```

EDIT
I tried to execute a debug and when I modify child_state, also parent.getState() is modified, they have the same memory reference (at the beginning of the "generate_child()" method I assign parent.getState() to child_state). How can I pass the value returned by parent.getState() (that is a matrix) to child_state without having the update of parent's state attibute ?

Comment: This is probably best solved using a debugger

Comment: I just edit the post @JoakimDanielson